# How do I record POST submissions in a text file?

Tags: forms, perl

I have a form with many fields. Let's simplify and pretend it's only got forename/surname/email here for now. I have to use Perl to process the form because I need to do other stuff with it later.

On submitting the form I need it to do three things:

1. To put the responses to this form into a text file on the server.
2. To send an email alert out saying that there's been a new form submitted. It doesn't need to contain the form data, just that a new one is there.
3. To display a “thanks for filling in the form” page to the person who's just hit submit.

I've tried concentrating on getting it to do any one of those things, but I still don't understand Perl enough to be able to do it. I'm a HTML user at best. It seems like a series of fairly simple things to do, and seems like the sort of thing for which there would be a "stock answer" somewhere, but a *lot* of Googling and reading of answers here hasn't given me anything! If I could just get some idea on how to do the first one, that would be a great start, but I can't even get that far… ☹

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: You've been working at this for a *year*? So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Plack](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack) and [MIME::Lite](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aLite).

   ```
   cpan Plack
   cpan MIME::Lite
   ```
2. Use plain HTML to build your form (name this `form.html` or whatever).

   ```html
   <form action="/send">
       <label>Enter some stuff:</label>
       <input type="text" name="stuff">
       <button type="submit">Send</button>
   </form>
   ```
3. Write a PSGI application (name this file `app.psgi`).

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use autodie;
   use Plack::App::File;
   use Plack::Builder;
   use Plack::Request;
   use MIME::Lite;

   builder {
       mount '/form.html' => Plack::App::File->new( file => "form.html" );
       mount '/send' => sub {
           my $req = Plack::Request->new($env);

           open my $fh, '>', 'form.txt';
           print $fh $req->content; # this will be ugly, but you didn't say what format
           close $fh;

           my $email = MIME::Lite->new(
               From => 'website@example.com',
               To => 'user@example.com',
               Subject => 'Form submitted from web site',
               Data => 'Read the subject.',
           );
           $email->send;

           return [ 
               200, 
               [ 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' ], 
               [ '<h1>Thanks for filling in the form.</h1>' ], 
           ];
       };
   ```
4. Run your web application:

   ```
   plackup --port 5000 app.psgi
   ```
5. Point your browser to: `http://localhost:5000`
6. Done.

This is not the best way to do any of this, but it is as very simple way to show how easy it is to get started and provides a basis to build out from.